# How to avoid prompt when opening gVim as external tool from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vim

I am trying to set up gVim 7.3 as an external tool to edit text from Visual Studio 2010.

Here is my argument list:

```
--servername VimStudio  --remote-silent +"runtime visualstudioinvoke.vim" +"call cursor($(CurLine), $(CurCol))" "$(ItemFileName)$(ItemExt)"
```

Everything works, but when I launch gVim as an external tool gVim requires me to

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Though this is not very burdensome, I would prefer to just have my cursor positioned and immediately ready to go.

I find that if I remove `+"runtime visualstudioinvoke.vim"` from the argument list and remove `set ruler` from my `_vimrc` file I can launch gVim as an external tool without the prompt.  My `visualstudioinvoke.vim` file just contains the single line :

```
normal zz
```

Is there a way to get gVim to launch from Visual Studio 2010 with my desired options without having to first press enter to get rid of the prompt?

Comment: Try `+"source visualstudioinvoke.vim"` or better `+"normal zz"`.

Comment: @romainl Neither of these solutions work for me, though I am not 100% on where they need to be placed in the command. If I comment out `set ruler` from my `_vimrc` they do remove the prompt, however they do not execute the `zz` command.